# How to implement NFC in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, nfc

So I was wondering if anyone knows how I can implement NFC usage into my app. The result I want by using NFC is when someone passes an NFC sensor with their phones in their pocket for example, the action triggers a notification for example but I do not know how to add NFC to the app and how the NFC necessarily interacts with in the iOS system. Also, is the code for NFC implementation available in Swift yet or is it only in Objective C so far? Thanks a lot in advance! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: That is a huge huge HUGE security risk that Apple would never allow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NFC is a very new thing for Apple, having only just added the chip to their new phones, 6 and 6 Plus. Unfortunately for you, they have made a decision to add not functionality at all in Xcode, and they have restricted NFC usage to Apple Pay only. That means trying to code a pairing system to Bluetooth speakers or a Touch ID-enabled way of exchanging contacts, URLs, and photos with a tap won’t work. However, Apple might in the future allow developing for NFC like they did with the Touch ID sensor in iOS 8. Unfortunately, for now, you won't be able to code for NFC.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news,

Will

Answer (score 0):

If you look past NFC you could get the exact functionality your looking for with iBeacon.

Comment: Hi! How could I use iBeacons to trigger an app that sends a unique ID to some place where someone can identify that person (for example, to make sure they're there)?

Comment: iBeacon apps can run in the background. So the iBeacon can trigger the app on the users phone to wake up and send some data to a server. This connects user (phone) with location of iBeacon and thereby the location.